# Routing App Coverage File missing but not needed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am submitting my app to the app store which uses location services (GPS dot) and `MKPinAnnotations` and doesn't use anything else for a map, and it looks from what I have researched that the Routing Coverage File is used for overlays?

I dont think I need a Routing Coverage File, but when I go to publish, xcode errors out saying it is missing in the Itunes Connect.

The category for the app is Utilities. It was also navigation but I unticked this hoping it would solve the issue and it didn't.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same issue earlier today when trying to publish an application that uses the MapKit but does not offer routing capabilities. I resolved it by deselecting *all supported routing modes* under '{Target} --> Capabilities --> Maps'. If you are just looking at the Info.plist file then you can remove the the `MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes` key and the `CFBundleTypeName` key that equals `MKDirectionsRequest`.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <!--Remove both of these key/value pairs -->
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MKDirectionsRequest</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.maps.directionsrequest</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and

```
<key>MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes</key>
<array>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeBike</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeBus</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeCar</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeFerry</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeOther</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModePedestrian</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModePlane</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeStreetCar</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeSubway</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeTaxi</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeTrain</string>
</array>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

turn off map capability solved my problem,

xcode - next to general tap, you should see capability tab,

scroll down to maps section, turn it off,

---

general tab, change you build and version different from last time,

re-upload to app store.

This time it would not ask for routing profile coverage file,

Done.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a long time to figure out, but the problem was with my scheme. It was the routing app coverage file location. I just change it to "None". Go to your scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> Routing App Coverage File, change it to None.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMrIq.png)